# Export all Microsoft Access tables into separate CSV files

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

I got an .mdb with 200 tables.
I want to write a vba routine that exports data into separate CSV.

On google I've found this code:

```
Public Sub ExportAllTablesToCSV()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim name As String
    
    For i = 0 To CurrentDb.TableDefs.Count
        name = CurrentDb.TableDefs(i).name
        
        If Not Left(name, 4) = "msys" And Not Left(name, 1) = "~" Then
            DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "", name, _
                "c:\exports\" & name & ".csv", _
                True
        End If
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

It seems ok but it wants a Export Specification (the parameter after acExportDelim"), this makes the script useless as I don't want to manually create 200 Export Specification.

Any idea?

Comment: Eh, that parameter is optional...

Comment: Leave it blank as per help page.

Comment: If I leave it blank I get an error "runtime error 3441".

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
    
Private Sub Command0_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_ExportDatabaseObjects
     
Dim db As Database
Dim td As TableDef
Dim d As Document
Dim c As Container
Dim i As Integer
Dim sExportLocation As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
     
sExportLocation = "C:\all_files\"

For Each td In db.TableDefs 'Tables
    If Left(td.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , td.Name, sExportLocation & "Table_" & td.Name & ".csv", True
    End If
    Next td
Set db = Nothing
Set c = Nothing

MsgBox "All database objects have been exported as a csv file to " & sExportLocation, vbInformation

Exit_ExportDatabaseObjects:
Exit Sub

Err_ExportDatabaseObjects:
MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
Resume Exit_ExportDatabaseObjects
     

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you shure you want CSV option? As this format with you can't import tables back to ms access (cause no data schema saved) so you need 200 files with schema. Ok if csv - there is a page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transfertext. Me, I tryed other more convinient way with XML In case you want to save your tables in convertible format

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim td As DAO.TableDefs

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set td = db.TableDefs
For Each t In td    'loop through all the fields of the tables
    'Ignore any system tables
    If Left(t.Name, 4) = "MSys" Then GoTo Continue
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, t.Name, , _
       (strPathAndFileName & t.Name & ".xml"), False   
Continue:
Next
```

`
You will be prompted for any t selected with format confirm
[format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOPt7.png) and [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcWB0.png)

So you have to click 3 x 200 times with keys or mouse, then in ~ten minutes work will be done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the customer wants csv format..

Comment: If you change ` DoCmd.OutputTo ` to 
`
      Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, DataSource:=t.Name, _
      DataTarget:=(strFolderName & "\" & t.Name & ".xml"), 
      otherflags:=acEmbedSchema
 `
Then all output will be done automaticaly. For import just easy as
`
     Application.ImportXML DataSource:=strFullpath, 
     ImportOptions:=acStructureAndData
`
It seems to me that there is no possible **valid CSV** import/export in modern Acess (O365 at least)